# Get PayPal Payer Status(verified/unverified)

Tags: orders, paypal, order-status

If you look at the "Payment Information" Tab of an order, you can see some details if it was paid with paypal like the "Payer Status"(Is the paypal verified?) or the email of the PayPal Account.

[image: Example of PayPal payment information]

**I'd like to get this informations programatically in an observer(where I have an `$order`)**, so I first looked at the fields of the `$order`: There is the `["additional_information"]["paypal_payer_status"]` in the protected `_data` array, so I could possibly get it by using Reflection(maybe not so good)
I tried also using the PayPal classes: `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/info.php` has a Method
`public function getPaymentInfo(Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment, $labelValuesOnly = false)`
which could probably provide the informations, but I was unable to create an instance of the class `Mage_Paypal_Model_Info`(has no constructer) containing this method(I guess the class isnt included/required while the code runs)

So I`d like to ask how to fix that or get the informations by a maybe more clean way.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the model `Mage_Paypal_Model_Info` you should be able to call `Mage::getModel('paypal/info')`.

Have a look at `Mage_Paypal_Block_Payment_Info::_prepareSpecificInformation()`, as this method appears to use the function that you desire:

```
protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
{
    $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
    $payment = $this->getInfo();
    $paypalInfo = Mage::getModel('paypal/info');
    if (!$this->getIsSecureMode()) {
        $info = $paypalInfo->getPaymentInfo($payment, true);
    } else {
        $info = $paypalInfo->getPublicPaymentInfo($payment, true);
    }

    return $transport->addData($info);
}
```